# Save data offline in a database

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, cordova

I'm wondering whether there is a technology similar to SQLite that would allow me to save data offline on different platforms including iPhone.

I'm using Phonegap so I don't know what the limitations are there, and whether it'd okay to use SQLite, or is there something better?

It's now working fine with Android, but will it be the same with iOS?

Comment: There are some information about limitations following link : http://grinninggecko.com/developing-cross-platform-html5-offline-app-1/

Comment: How are you doing it in Android?  What have you tried for iOS?

Comment: @Jonmorgan : I use SQLite with Android.

Answer (score 1):

See the [PhoneGap Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) that's based on the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C Web Storage API Specification. It's implemented for Android, IOS, and Blackberry.